# Getting "Undefined Control Sequence" error after converting compiler from pdfLaTeX to either of XeLaTex or LuaLaTex

Tags: xetex, luatex, fontawesome

I am writing a resume based off of https://github.com/sb2nov/resume (check the .tex file here for the exact code that I am using). I tried to bring in the `fontawesome` package in order to use LinkedIn and GitHub icons. However, `fontawesome` is apparently not compatible with pdfLaTeX and the compiler gave me an error saying that I have to change the compiler to XeLaTex or LuaLatex in order to run the `fontawesome` package commands such as `\faGithub` and `\faLinkedin`.

So I changed my compiler engine to either of those, and then I get the "Undefined Control Sequence" error repeatedly for so many lines in my log output. Here is an image of the log output:

[image: The log output:]

Can someone please help me how to resolve this error? The file was compiling perfectly with pdfLaTeX or LaTeX engine in Overleaf. Even before using the `fontawesome` package, as soon as I change the compiler to xeLaTex on the original resume template it gave me the same long log output of errors. So, I am assuming that there is something in the code that is not compatible with xeLaTeX? I haven't used XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX before so maybe I am missing something which needs to be added to my code? Hope someone can help!

Comment: Don't link to external sites for code, add a small but complete example here. The error indicates the you input glyphtounicode. Don't do this with this engines.

Comment: Remove `\usepackage{glyphtounicode}` and  `\pdfgentounicode=1` from your code.

Comment: @Ingmar glyphtounicode is not a sty, it is input with \input.

Comment: I know that, but her Github-template used it that way.

Comment: Thanks so much, everyone! Removing the `glyphtounicode` and `pdfgentounicode` lines did the job.

Comment: Also, @UlrikeFischer sorry, I know not to link to external sites here, but since I had no idea where the problem in the code was and the code was very long, I saw no choice but to link to the main source that I am using. But thanks for the tip.

Comment: generally it is not very difficult (and doesn't need much time) to shorten code if the error is in the preamble. Simply copy your file in some test folder and then comment one half of the preamble, and check if the error was in it.